# Panning multiple images simultaniosly

Tags: ios, ipad, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

I want to know if it is possible to drag/pan multiple images simultaneously using multitouch

ie: use 1 finger to drag one image while using the other finger to drag another image at the same time
and i want to implement this using a UIGestureRecognizer.

If so i would like to know how should i go about this .

EDIT : The code im using for panning

```
CGPoint ltouch = [gestureRecognizer translationInView:self.view];
if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) 
{
      self.pointOnImage = [gestureRecognizer view].center;
}
ltouch = CGPointMake(self.pointOnImage.x + ltouch.x, self.pointOnImage.y + ltouch.y);

[gestureRecognizer.view  setCenter:CGPointMake(ltouch.x, ltouch.y)];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes this is possible you can download a zip from [here](https://github.com/AalokParikh/pinch-and-uiguesture)
this shows how to do it. it is not my created demo but found on some site

Comment: I went through your code and im still not getting where im going wrong
Ive posted my code above it would be nice if you could point out the flaw :-/